# What is the alternative class in Harmony OS for AccelerateInterpolator and OvershootInterpolator in Android OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am writing a class in JAVA to port a library from Android to Harmony OS.
In the Android code given below for the method `onSelectedY(boolean, float, int)`, it requires a constructor of the class `AccelerateInterpolator` to be added to a method

```
private void onSelectedY(final boolean isTop, float exitX, int duration)
{
        ....
        ....

        this.frame.animate()
                .setDuration(duration)
                .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
                .x(exitX)
                .y(exitY)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
                    {
                        if(isTop)
                        {
                            mFlingListener.onCardExited();
                            mFlingListener.topExit(dataObject);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mFlingListener.onCardExited();
                            mFlingListener.bottomExit(dataObject);
                        }
                        isAnimationRunning = false;
                    }
                })
                .rotation(getVerticalExitRotation(isTop));
}
```

For equivalent Harmony OS component of class `AccelerateInterpolator`, there is an interface named `Animator.TimelineCurve`.
But the issue with it being an interface is that it doesn't have a constructor, which is needed in this case. If I directly use the interface, I would have to override the interface here itself, but that can't be done as there is nothing to override manually.

Same goes for `OvershootInterpolator`.

What could be the work-around for this case?

Regards, Subham

Answer (score 2):

**ohos.agp.animation.Animator.CurveType** is equivalent API for **Interpolators** in Android. You have to make use of **setCurveType(int)** API, and for **AccelerateInterpolator** you have to use **Animator.CurveType.ACCELERATE**. For **OvershootInterpolator** use **Animator.CurveType.OVERSHOOT**,

Usage:

```java
    animator.setCurveType(Animator.CurveType.ACCELERATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the [this development documentation](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ui-java-animation-0000000000580278#section11492135193619) to see if it helps.

In addition, there are two implementations of the TimelineCurve class: [CubicBezierCurve](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/cubicbeziercurve-0000001138987471) and [SpringCurve](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/springcurve-0000001138830325).